# What is the best way to use speech biasing hints when using ActionsSdkApp?

Tags: actions-on-google

What is the best way to use speech biasing hints when using ActionsSdkApp?

https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppResponse#expectedinput

Comment: Hey @sysCoder I'm checking the topic as it seems that you might be able to use...

Comment: I'm VERY interested in making use of this too. Please let me know what you figure out guys. I vote for this being exposed in the APIs... There are some use cases where this is REALLY needed. Like recognising a constrained list of proper nouns.

Comment: Have either of you got any further with speechBiasingHints? I've tried it on an ActionsSDK project (i.e. No Dialogflow) and I cannot perceive any difference in the rec performance. In fact it still makes the (crazy?) 'near-homophone' mistakes I was trying to fix, such as "beauty" -> "pewdie". I feel like it is not plumbed in as documented...